TileMap set_cell invisible tiles. Setting up TileSet in code
I create TileSetAtlasSource in code:
var atlas_source = TileSetAtlasSource.new()
atlas_source.texture = atlas_texture  # Tileset image with all the tiles in it
tileset.add_source(atlas_source, 0)  # Adding it to the TileSet with ID 0

Then I go through the tiles and create them to be used later:
for y in atlas_size.y:
    for x in atlas_size.x:
        atlas.create_tile(Vector2i(x, y))

The problem is that when I call set_cell method to check if everything is alright:
for x in 16:
    for y in 16:
        TileMap.set_cell(0, Vector2i(x, y), 0, Vector2i(x, y))  # Layer 0, then coordinates on TileMap, then source ID (which is 0), and lastly tile coords

the tiles are not shown. Though the atlas texture itself appears correctly. Where did I go wrong?
Note: If I set everything manually through the editor, it works as intended. All the tiles show normally.

just to sort out any configuration errors, because I can't reproduce the error (same setup works for me):

"tileset" is the same as TileMap.tile_set?
TileMap is a node in your scene and Point Cell 0/0 to 15/15 are visible in your viewport?


1.Yes; 2. Yes. I put TileMap node in the center just to be sure, and if I set the tiles in the editor - everything is seen. Btw, I'm using Compatibility renderer, the Forward+ is causing problems sometimes on my iGPU

hmm. I have no idea why it's not working for you. I created a project with your provided code, which is working for me: https://github.com/bugfi5h/TileMapSetCell/tree/main/StackCompati    It uses the default image from godot, which is half the size of your image, but the rest is 1:1 your code from this and the other question.
you could check, if this project is working for you too and if so we can search for diffrences between the two projects

I went by your script, line by line, and I'm sorry, but I'm a **** idiot. I forgot to declare the tilset I created in code as TileMap.tile_set = created_tileset ((( Anyway, thank you for helping me out :D

if you create stuff in code... NEVER FORGET to check if you declared things and assigned them to where they should be!
In this case, I forgot to assign the already working TileSet to a completely functional TileMap
